# How to update password in flutter using Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Hi guys I'm new in flutter and I'm trying to make an update password based on the user data that stored in the firestore and also based on the user current login to the system. Anyone know how to update password based on certain ID that login to the system and validate it when the user enter the repeat password? Please help.

Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/localization/localization_constants.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/setting.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/theme/colors.dart';


class BackupSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BackupSettingsState createState() => _BackupSettingsState();
}

class _BackupSettingsState extends State<BackupSettings> {
  final _newpasswordController = TextEditingController();
  final _repeatpasswordController = TextEditingController();
  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  
  

  bool checkCurrentPasswordValid = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(getTranslated(context, 'backup_text'),),
        elevation: 0,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        backgroundColor: primary,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Settings()));
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.black,),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
              key: _formKey,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (input) {
                          if (input.length < 8)
                            return 'Please Provide Minimum 8 Character';
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: getTranslated(context, 'new_password'),
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.lock,
                            color: secondary,
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                          ),
                        ),
                        obscureText: true,
                        controller: _newpasswordController
                        ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: getTranslated(context, 'repeat_password'),
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.lock,
                          color: secondary,
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                        ),
                      ),
                      obscureText: true,
                        controller: _repeatpasswordController,
                      validator: (value) {
                        return _newpasswordController.text == value
                            ? null
                            : "Please validate your entered password";
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  RaisedButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 10, 70, 10),
                    onPressed: (){
                      
                    },

                    child: Text(getTranslated(context, 'save_button'),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    color: primary,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, may I know how to that?

Comment: hi may I know how to do that?

Comment: Are you using Firebase Authentication and still storing the password in Firestore?

Comment: yes I'm using firebase authentication and storing to the firestore @Dharmaraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function,

```
void _changePassword(String yourPassword) async{
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    user.updatePassword(yourPassword).then((_){
Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(user.uid).updateData(
         {
          "password" : _newpasswordController.text,
         }).then((_){
          print("Successfully changed password");
         });
    }).catchError((error){
      print("Error " + error.toString());
    });
  }
```

on press,

```
    onPressed: (){
if(!_formKey.currentState.validate()){
return;
}
_formKey.currentState.save();
             _changePassword(_newpasswordController.text);      
        },
```

Comment: and what should I input in on press button?

Comment: check edited answer. let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: I check the password in the firestore it did not change but in the run it shows D/FirebaseAuth(27924): Notifying id token listeners about user ( PyDw717LcSTofi7dB4d3kV9QhIY2 ).
W/System  (27924): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/flutter (27924): Successfully changed password.

Comment: but in the run it show successfully changed password, but actually it did not change the password (in firestore)

Comment: it will not change password in firestore database. it will change in authentication table. for change in db you have to update that particular user data. check updated answer.

Comment: oh yess!! thank you it works. but how can I validate the text fields if the text fields are empty and if the new password text fields is not the same with the repeat password text fields?

Comment: I got this error The method 'validate' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: validate()